# Well-known quotations

Tags: knowledge, movies, anagram

Continuing the Movie theme, can you unravel the well-known quotes below?
I would encourage teamwork with this one.

1. `4:0:0:0:6:1:1:0:3:0:1:1:1:5:4:0:0:2:2:3:0:1:1:0:1:0 (4, 1'2 1 7 2'2 3 2 6 7.)`
   Said by JG (1939)
2. `1:0:0:1:2:0:1:1:2:0:2:1:0:1:3:0:0:1:1:1:1:0:0:0:1:0 (4'1 7 2 3, 3.)`
   Said by HB (1942)
3. `3:0:0:0:3:3:1:1:4:0:0:2:3:3:2:0:0:1:0:3:0:1:0:0:3:0 (6, 6, 4'2 3 3 2 2 3 2!)`
   Said by KW (1964)
4. `0:2:0:3:3:2:0:1:0:0:0:3:0:1:10:2:0:2:3:2:2:0:1:0:3:0 (3'2 4 8 2 4 3 6 5 3!)`
   Said by MC (1969)
5. `4:0:1:0:5:3:1:2:2:0:1:0:3:4:2:0:0:2:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0 (1'1 5 4 3 2 5 2 3'1 6.)`
   Said by MB (1972)
6. `3:2:0:1:4:0:3:0:1:0:0:0:0:3:3:0:0:2:0:1:1:0:0:0:1:0 (3'2 5 4 1 6 4.)`
   Said by RS (1975)
7. `1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:1:1:2:0:0:0:0:2:1:0:0:0:1:0 (3 6' 2 2?)`
   Said by RdN (1976)
8. `1:0:0:2:5:1:1:2:2:0:1:1:0:2:6:0:0:4:2:3:1:0:0:0:1:0 (5 3 3 3 5 3'2 7 3.)`
   Said by AG (1977)
9. `3:1:0:0:5:0:1:5:1:0:0:0:1:2:2:0:0:1:4:3:1:1:0:0:3:0 (2'1 3 3 7. 2'1 1 4 7 3!)`
   Said by TJ (1979)
10. `0:0:0:0:3:0:0:2:0:0:0:0:1:1:2:1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (2 5 4.)`
    Said by DB (1982)
11. `4:0:0:2:2:0:1:1:0:0:1:0:2:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2:0 (2 5, 4 2 3.)`
    Said by CE (1983)
12. `1:0:0:1:3:1:0:1:2:0:0:4:1:1:2:0:0:1:1:3:0:0:0:0:2:0 (3 5 2 2 6 6.)`
    Said by AP (1983)
13. `1:2:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:2:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1'2 2 4.)`
    Said by AS (1984)
14. `4:0:6:0:0:1:1:6:4:0:1:2:2:3:3:2:0:0:2:4:0:0:2:0:2:0 (3 3 5 3 4 9 10 8.)`
    Said by PM (1984)
15. `1:0:0:3:7:0:2:1:1:0:0:0:0:3:3:0:0:3:1:1:0:0:3:0:0:0 (5 2'2 5 2 3'1 4 5)`
    Said by CL (1985)
16. `2:1:1:3:3:0:0:0:3:0:0:5:0:2:5:4:0:0:3:5:5:0:1:0:1:0 (2 4 3 6 5 2 2 6 2 6 6!)`
    Said by JLC (1988)
17. `0:1:1:1:2:1:0:1:4:0:0:3:1:0:2:0:0:0:0:1:2:0:1:0:1:0 (2 3 5 2, 2 4 4.)`
    Said by RL (1989)
18. `5:1:1:3:8:0:0:1:4:0:1:1:2:1:3:1:0:5:3:2:1:1:0:1:4:1 (5 4. 5 3 3, 4. 4 4 5 13.)`
    Said by RW (1989)
19. `7:1:2:1:5:1:0:3:7:0:0:1:1:4:1:0:0:1:3:3:0:2:1:0:0:0 (1 3 3 5 4 4 4 5 3 1 4 7.)`
    Said by AH (1991)
20. `2:0:1:1:2:0:0:3:0:0:0:1:0:2:1:0:0:1:0:4:2:0:0:0:1:0 (3 3'1 6 3 5.)`
    Said by JN (1992)
21. `0:2:0:1:2:0:4:0:3:0:0:1:0:2:1:0:0:1:2:2:2:1:0:0:3:0 (3 4 6, 2 3 4 5.)`
    Said by TR (1994)
22. `4:0:1:5:6:1:5:1:4:0:0:0:0:8:9:0:0:1:2:3:0:1:0:0:1:0 (2 4 1 3'1 3 2, 4 9, 4 7, 3 4 5!)`
    Said by JC (1998)
23. `1:0:0:2:5:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0:1:2:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 3 4 6.)`
    Said by HJO (1999)
24. `0:1:1:1:3:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:0:0:2:1:1:1:1:0:0:2:0 (9 4, 5.)`
    Said by TC (2002)
25. `1:0:0:2:0:2:0:0:8:0:2:9:0:2:6:0:0:1:0:0:3:0:3:0:3:0 (1 4 4 3 3, 1 4 4 3 3 1 4 4 3.)`
    Said by LN (2008)
26. `0:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:2:0:0:1:3:0:1:0:1:0:1:0 (3 2 7?)`
    Said by HL (2008)
27. `3:0:1:1:2:6:2:4:3:0:1:3:2:4:7:0:0:1:3:3:3:0:0:0:3:0 (2 2 4, 4 2 4 6 7! 2'1 2 6, 1'1 5 3!)`
    Said by EF (2010)
28. `1:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:2:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 2 5.)`
    Said by VD (2014)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the rules are (thanks to Kate Gregory and Deusovi for these):
1. The numbers separated by colons indicate the number of occurrences of each letter of the alphabet in the quote (the first being A and the last being Z).
2. The numbers in parentheses indicate the length of each word in the quote, along with punctuation.
3. The second line indicates the initials of the actor/actress attributed with the quote alongside the year of the release of the movie containing the quote.

`4:0:0:0:6:1:1:0:3:0:1:1:1:5:4:0:0:2:2:3:0:1:1:0:1:0 (4, 1'2 1 7 2'2 3 2 6 7.)
Said by JG (1939)`

> "Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore." The Wizard of Oz 1939 Judy Garland (Kate Gregory)

`1:0:0:1:2:0:1:1:2:0:2:1:0:1:3:0:0:1:1:1:1:0:0:0:1:0 (4'1 7 2 3, 3.)
Said by HB (1942)`

> "Here's looking at you, kid." Casablanca 1942 Humphrey Bogart

`3:0:0:0:3:3:1:1:4:0:0:2:3:3:2:0:0:1:0:3:0:1:0:0:3:0 (6, 6, 4'2 3 3 2 2 3 2!)
Said by KW (1964)`

> "Infamy, infamy, they've all got it in for me!" Carry On Cleo 1964 Kenneth Williams

`0:2:0:3:3:2:0:1:0:0:0:3:0:1:10:2:0:2:3:2:2:0:1:0:3:0 (3'2 4 8 2 4 3 6 5 3!)
Said by MC (1969)`

> "You're only supposed to blow the bloody doors off!" The Italian Job 1969 Michael Caine

`4:0:1:0:5:3:1:2:2:0:1:0:3:4:2:0:0:2:1:1:1:0:0:0:0:0 (1'1 5 4 3 2 5 2 3'1 6.)
Said by MB (1972)`

> "I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse." The Godfather 1972 Marlon Brando

`3:2:0:1:4:0:3:0:1:0:0:0:0:3:3:0:0:2:0:1:1:0:0:0:1:0 (3'2 5 4 1 6 4.)
Said by RS (1975)`

> "You're gonna need a bigger boat." Jaws 1975 Roy Scheider

`1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:1:1:2:0:0:0:0:2:1:0:0:0:1:0 (3 6' 2 2?)
Said by RdN (1976)`

> "You talkin' to me?" Taxi Driver 1976 Robert deNiro (Kate Gregory)

`1:0:0:2:5:1:1:2:2:0:1:1:0:2:6:0:0:4:2:3:1:0:0:0:1:0 (5 3 3 3 5 3'2 7 3.)
Said by AG (1977)`

> "These are not the droids you're looking for." Star Wars 1977 Alec Guinness (corsiKa)

`3:1:0:0:5:0:1:5:1:0:0:0:1:2:2:0:0:1:4:3:1:1:0:0:3:0 (2'1 3 3 7. 2'1 1 4 7 3!)
Said by TJ (1979)`

> "He's not the Messiah. He's a very naughty boy!" Monty Python's Life of Brian 1979 Terry Jones

`0:0:0:0:3:0:0:2:0:0:0:0:1:1:2:1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (2 5 4.)
Said by DB (1982)`

> ET Phone Home - E.T. 1982 Drew Barrymore (alexmc)

`4:0:0:2:2:0:1:1:0:0:1:0:2:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2:0 (2 5, 4 2 3.)
Said by CE (1983)`

> "Go ahead, make my day." Sudden Impact 1983 Clint Eastwood

`1:0:0:1:3:1:0:1:2:0:0:4:1:1:2:0:0:1:1:3:0:0:0:0:2:0 (3 5 2 2 6 6.)
Said by AP (1983)`

> "Say hello to my little friend." Scarface 1983 Al Pacino (How did I not get that sooner!)

`1:2:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:2:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1'2 2 4.)
Said by AS (1984)`

> "I'll be back" The Terminator 1984 Arnold Schwarzenegger (alexmc)

`4:0:6:0:0:1:1:6:4:0:1:2:2:3:3:2:0:0:2:4:0:0:2:0:2:0 (3 3 5 3 4 9 10 8.)
Said by PM (1984)`

> "Man who catch fly with chopstick accomplish anything." Karate Kid 1984 Pat Morita

`1:0:0:3:7:0:2:1:1:0:0:0:0:3:3:0:0:3:1:1:0:0:3:0:0:0 (5 2'2 5 2 3'1 4 5)
Said by CL (1985)`

> "Where we're going we don't need roads" Back to the Future 1985 Christopher Lloyd

`2:1:1:3:3:0:0:0:3:0:0:5:0:2:5:4:0:0:3:5:5:0:1:0:1:0 (2 4 3 6 5 2 2 6 2 6 6!)
Said by JLC (1988)`

> "To call you stupid would be an insult to stupid people!" A Fish Called Wanda 1988 Jamie Lee Curtis

`0:1:1:1:2:1:0:1:4:0:0:3:1:0:2:0:0:0:0:1:2:0:1:0:1:0 (2 3 5 2, 2 4 4.)
Said by RL (1989)`

> "If you build it, he will come." Field of Dreams 1989 Ray Liotta

`5:1:1:3:8:0:0:1:4:0:1:1:2:1:3:1:0:5:3:2:1:1:0:1:4:1 (5 4. 5 3 3, 4. 4 4 5 13.)
Said by RW (1989)`

> "Carpe diem. Seize the day, boys. Make your lives extraordinary." Dead Poet's Society 1989 Robin Williams (alexmc)

`7:1:2:1:5:1:0:3:7:0:0:1:1:4:1:0:0:1:3:3:0:2:1:0:0:0 (1 3 3 5 4 4 4 5 3 1 4 7.)
Said by AH (1991)`

> "I ate his liver with some fava beans and a nice chianti." The Silence of the Lambs 1991 Anthony Hopkins

`2:0:1:1:2:0:0:3:0:0:0:1:0:2:1:0:0:1:0:4:2:0:0:0:1:0 (3 3'1 6 3 5.)
Said by JN (1992)`

> "You can't handle the truth." A Few Good Men 1992 Jack Nicholson

`0:2:0:1:2:0:4:0:3:0:0:1:0:2:1:0:0:1:2:2:2:1:0:0:3:0 (3 4 6, 2 3 4 5.)
Said by TR (1994)`

> "Get busy living, or get busy dying." Shawshank Redemption 1994 Tim Robbins (alexmc)

`4:0:1:5:6:1:5:1:4:0:0:0:0:8:9:0:0:1:2:3:0:1:0:0:1:0 (2 4 1 3'1 3 2, 4 9, 4 7, 3 4 5!)
Said by JC (1998)`

> "In case I don't see ya, good afternoon, good evening, and good night!" The Truman Show 1998 Jim Carrey

`1:0:0:2:5:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0:1:2:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 3 4 6.)
Said by HJO (1999)`

> "I see dead people." The Sixth Sense 1999 Haley Joel Osment (Kate Gregory)

`0:1:1:1:3:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:0:0:2:1:1:1:1:0:0:2:0 (9 4, 5.)
Said by TC (2002)`

> "Everybody runs, Fletch." Minority Report 2002 Tom Cruise (alexmc)

`1:0:0:2:0:2:0:0:8:0:2:9:0:2:6:0:0:1:0:0:3:0:3:0:3:0 (1 4 4 3 3, 1 4 4 3 3 1 4 4 3.)
Said by LN (2008)`

> "I will look for you, I will find you and I will kill you." Taken 2008 Liam Neeson (Wa Kai)

`0:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:2:0:0:1:3:0:1:0:1:0:1:0 (3 2 7?)
Said by HL (2008)`

> "Why so serious?" Batman:The Dark Knight 2008 Heath Ledger (alexmc)

`3:0:1:1:2:6:2:4:3:0:1:3:2:4:7:0:0:1:3:3:3:0:0:0:3:0 (2 2 4, 4 2 4 6 7! 2'1 2 6, 1'1 5 3!)
Said by EF (2010)`

> "Oh my gosh, look at that fluffy unicorn! He's so fluffy, I'm gonna die!" Despicable Me 2010 Elsie Fisher

`1:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:2:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 2 5.)
Said by VD (2014)`

> "I am groot" Guardians of the Galaxy 2014 Vin Diesel (alexmc)

Comment: I thought this answer had it all, but after I realized you didn't have 1977 AG, I realized this wasn't the post I was looking for. *Makes handwave motion*

Comment: @corsiKa that went right over my head. I seemed peculiar but I didn't make the connection. Thanks for the help! Based on the letters, I even had "you're ....ing" but still looked right over. Geez

Comment: Did you need the letter frequencies to get these answers or did you get most of them just from the number of letters, the initial and the year?

Comment: @GordonK The letter frequencies went almost entirely unused (though they did confirm some suspicions) 1977 was the only one where I tried to get it purely from the letter frequencies.

Answer (score 6):

The key is:

> The 26 numbers denote the frequency of each letter in the quote - the following bracketed numbers are the number of letters in each word with added punctuation.

13. `1:2:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:2:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1'2 2 4.)
    Said by AS (1984)`

> I'll be back - Arnold Schwarzenegger (Terminator)

23. `1:0:0:2:5:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0:1:2:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 3 4 6.)
    Said by HJO (1999)`

> I see dead people - Hayley Joel Osment (The Sixth Sense)

28. `1:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:2:0:0:1:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 2 5.)
    Said by VD (2014)`

> I am groot - Vin Diesel (Guardians of the Galaxy)

10. `0:0:0:0:3:0:0:2:0:0:0:0:1:1:2:1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0 (2 5 4.)
    Said by DB (1982)`

> ET Phone Home - Drew Barrymore (E.T.)

26. `0:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:1:0:0:0:0:0:2:0:0:1:3:0:1:0:1:0:1:0 (3 2 7?)
    Said by HL (2008)`

> Why So Serious? - Heath Ledger (The Dark Knight)

18. `5:1:1:3:8:0:0:1:4:0:1:1:2:1:3:1:0:5:3:2:1:1:0:1:4:1 (5 4. 5 3 3, 4. 4 4 5 13.)
    Said by RW (1989)`

> Carpe diem. Seize the day, boys. Make your lives extraordinary. - Robin Williams (Dead Poet's Society)

24. `0:1:1:1:3:1:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:0:0:2:1:1:1:1:0:0:2:0 (9 4, 5.)
    Said by TC (2002)`

> Everybody runs, Fletch. - Tom Cruise (Minority Report)

21. `0:2:0:1:2:0:4:0:3:0:0:1:0:2:1:0:0:1:2:2:2:1:0:0:3:0 (3 4 6, 2 3 4 5.)
    Said by TR (1994)`

> Get busy living, or get busy dying. - Tim Robbins (Shawshank Redemption)

12. `4:0:0:2:2:0:1:1:0:0:1:0:2:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2:0 (2 5, 4 2 3.)
    Said by CE (1983)`

> Go ahead, make my day. - Clint Eastwood (Sudden Impact)

Answer (score 3):

7. `1:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:1:0:1:1:1:1:2:0:0:0:0:2:1:0:0:0:1:0 (3 6' 2 2?)
   Said by RdN (1976)`

This would be `You talkin' to me?` by Robert de Niro giving the following pieces of information:

- the initials are of the actor, not the character
- the parentheses are word length and the presence of apostrophes

Therefore:

1. `4:0:0:0:6:1:1:0:3:0:1:1:1:5:4:0:0:2:2:3:0:1:1:0:1:0 (4, 1'2 1 7 2'2 3 2 6 7.)
   Said by JG (1939)`

> `Toto, I've a feeling we're not in Kansas anymore.` by Judy Garland

23. `1:0:0:2:5:0:0:0:1:0:0:1:0:0:1:2:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 (1 3 4 6.)
    Said by HJO (1999)`

> `I see dead people.` by Haley J Osment

Comment: That's a good start.

Comment: And the numbers are the amount of each letter. (For example, in the first quote, the second last number is 1, so there's one of the second last letter (Y).)

Answer (score 2):

```
25)  1:0:0:2:0:2:0:0:8:0:2:9:0:2:6:0:0:1:0:0:3:0:3:0:3:0 (1 4 4 3 3, 1 4 4 3 3 1 4 4 3.)
Said by LN (2008)
```

> Is Liam Neeson with:
>     I will look for you, I will find you and I will kill you.